# Using javascript regex to parse strings starting with "$" and other conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a difficult regex to wrap my head around. I'd like to get all words that start with a `$`. The conditions are:

- string must start with `$` and the preceding character must either be beginning of string or a space.
- if `$` is followed by `"`, then everything in between the `""` must be captured. Both quotes must be present or nothing is captured.
- `""` is only used for capturing more than one word
- `$` by itself will not match anything

Some examples:

- `Bob gave Jane $4`

  ["4"] captured
- `$"10 Thousand Dollars" is a lot more than $1 and $-3`

  ["10 Thousand Dollars", "1", "-3"] captured
- `Bob paid $590 to $Micro$oft $and" wa$ reimbursed $Nine`

  ["590", "Micro$oft", "Nine"] captured
- `Alice says $"Hello $World!"`

  ["Hello $World!"] captured
- `$ Yup$`

  Nothing is captured

I tried [playing around](http://scriptular.com/#[%5Cs%5CW%5CS%5Cs]%2B%3F%5C%24%28%3F%3D%28%5C%22%3F[%5Cs%5Cw%5CW%5CS%5Cd]%2B%5C%22%3F%29%29*[%5Cw%5CW%5CS%5Cs]%2B%3F%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C[%22Bob%20paid%20%24590%20to%20%24Micro%24oft%20%24and%5C%22%20wa%24%20reimbursed%20%24Nine%22]) but it is horrible. The look-aheads make this really tricky.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dI3vZ0/1

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. If you make an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function parse(text) {
    var re = /(\s|^)\$(?:"([^"]*)"|([^\s"]+)(?!\S))/g;
    re.lastIndex = 0;
    var result = [];
    var match;
    while (match = re.exec(text)) {
        result.push(match[2] || match[3]);
    }
    return result;
}

var tests = [
  'Bob gave Jane $4',
  '$"10 Thousand Dollars" is a lot more than $1 and $-3',
  'Bob paid $590 to $Micro$oft $and" wa$ reimbursed $Nine',
  'Alice says $"Hello $World!"',
  '$ Yup$'
];

$('<table>').append([
  $('<thead>').append([
    $('<tr>').append([
      $('<th>').text('Test'),
      $('<th>').text('Captures')
    ])
  ]),
  $('<tbody>').append(
    $.map(tests, function (test) {
      var result = parse(test);
      return $('<tr>').append([
        $('<td>').append([
          $('<code>').text(test)
        ]),
        $('<td>').append([
          $('<code>').text(JSON.stringify(result))
        ])
      ]);
    })
  )
]).appendTo('#output23');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output23"></div>
```